# access to top level widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How i can access to `top level widget` from function, which used as command for button or menu? There is way to add params in this command function by using `command=lambda: f(params)`, but i think it may be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lambda, like you mentioned:

```
command=lambda: f(params)
```

or you could make a closure:

```
def make_callback(params):
    def callback():
        print(params)
    return callback
params = 1,2,3
button = tk.Button(master, text='Boink', command=make_callback(params))
```

or, you could use a class and pass a bound method. The attributes of `self` can contain the information that you would otherwise have had to pass as parameters.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.params = (1,2,3)
        self.button = tk.Button(master, text='Boink', command=self.boink)
        self.button.pack()
    def boink(self):
        print(self.params)

root = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your lambda and your explicit def are both closures.

Comment: The lambda itself is not a closure, as it does not close over `params`.

Comment: The `lambda` is a closure if and only if `params` is in non-global scope at the time you create the function. And the same is true for the `def`. Try replacing `command=lambda: f(params)` with `def command(): return f(params)`, and try replacing the body of `make_callback` with `return lambda: f(params)`.